# Percentage or Ratio using two values in nano seconds

Tags: percentages, ratio, discrete-time

I am running two different python code, one using a for loop and the other numpy library in python and I have timed it using `%timeit` function, yet I don't understand how to convert the two-time values into a percentage or ratio.  This is the direct output from each test.

**First time**
$15.4 µs ± 26.9 ns$ per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
**Second time**
$9.07 µs ± 570 ns$ per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

The worst part is, I do not really know which one is "faster" perse, technically the second time should?  I also would like to understand how to put this into a form say percentage or ratio that is easier to understand and would appreciate your help.

Comment: So you want to calculate a percentage or ratio. Which values do you want to compare? The two "times"? That is, the 15.4 and 9.07, to see which one is bigger?

Comment: The 26.9 ns and 570ns.  As in if you could describe one as being faster than the other, by how much, i.e. 20 times faster, 22 times faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plot them.  What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: That is definitely a, "slaps forehead", moment, cheers! :)